# Updating portfolio website made from HTML5,CSS3, Bootstrap and JavaScript to REACT

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, bootstrap-5

I have made my portfolio website using HTML5, CSS3, Bootstrap and JS. Now I want to convert it into REACT. How can I do that efficiently? Any suggestion?
[ Live link to my portfolio website: ]
( https://rajahumzanawaz.github.io/Web-Development-Labs/Web%20Assignment%202/index.html

Comment: react is for constant updating info display, why do you need that for a portfolio?

Comment: gotta rewrite it lol. You can use react for building components and compartmentalizing your code, but you could also use something like [jade](https://jade-lang.com/) instead of react though